# Access redux store from redux-simple-router children

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm trying to figure out how to access the redux store from within route so I can dispatch actions from within the route.

Here's what my top level Component looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         { children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My redux-simple-router code looks like:

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
        <Route path="/example" component={ ExampleRoute } />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```

If I dump props from within the ExampleRoute component, I don't have access to the store.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `connect` from `react-redux` to get `dispatch` and current state from the store. It is outlined in the redux docs here: http://rackt.org/redux/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Here is your `Example` component:

```
//...
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
//...

export class Example extends Component {
    render () {
        const { dispatch, thingName } = this.props
        return (
            <button onClick={ () => {
                dispatch(myAwesomeActionCreator())
            }}>{ thingName }</button>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(state => state)(Example)
```

Some good examples of how to use `connect` can be found in the `react-redux` docs: https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#examples

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with "Monkeypatch" middleware, but there's got to be a better way.

First I created a function to monkeypatch the children variable.  This function takes the child, the dispatch and the store as arguments, and returns an updated children variable with keys for the store and dispatch:

```
function routeStoreMiddleware (children, dispatch, store) {
  return {
    ...children,
    props: {
      ...children.props,
      dispatch: dispatch,
      store: store
    }
  }
}
```

Then I simply updated the component that already has access to the dispatch and store to consume the middleware function:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         { routeStoreMiddleware(children, dispatch, store) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Since the poorly named routeStoreMiddleware function simply returns an updated children object, it still works.

Now I can dispatch events and display data from within the ExampleRoute component.

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { myAwesomeActionCreator } from '../actions.js'

```
export class Example extends Component {
  render () {
    const { dispatch, store } = this.props
    return (
      <button onClick={ () => {
        dispatch(myAwesomeActionCreator())
      }}>{ store.thingName }</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Yay!

**Please note:**
I've been [reading a lot here](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) about how to make middleware properly in redux, but I haven't had time yet to understand it fully.  There's a better way than I've done here.